# How to open Ubuntu's bash.exe shell using C# on Windows?

Tags: c#, bash, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

as described in the title, I wanna open up the ubuntu-shell on my windows pc, passing a
"cd /mnt/c/users/xyz/desktop" to it then passing a
"python3 some_script.py arg1, arg2" to it

all this works wonderful if done manually via mouseclicks but from code (see below:)
it doesnt write anything to the console which opens.

```
        string ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            // Execute wsl command:                
            var StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {                    
                FileName = @"bash.exe",
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32",
                //Arguments = "/c " + "root@DESKTOP-OUTEVME:~#",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,           
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            };
            using (var process = Process.Start(StartInfo)) 
            {
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine();
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(e.Data);
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);                 
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                process.WaitForExit();
                //result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
            }
            return result;                
        }
        return ExecuteCommand(@"wsl cd /mnt/c/users/shho3/desktop");
```

Anyone maybe an idea what I could do wrong?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass everything in the command line instead of piping into the process. I think it would save you a lot of trouble. Try `bash.exe -c "cd /mnt/c/Users/shho3/Desktop; python some_script.py arg1 arg2"`:

```cs
Process.Start("bash.exe", "-c \"cd /mnt/c/Users/shho3/Desktop; python some_script.py arg1 arg2\"").WaitForExit()
```

Alternatively you can also just set the working directory to `C:\Users\shho3\Desktop` (instead of `C:\Windows\System32`) and call `bash.exe -c "python some_script.py arg1 arg2"`, then you don't even have to convert the path:

```cs
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("bash.exe", "-c \"python some_script.py arg1 arg2\"") {
  WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\ssho3\\Desktop"
}).WaitForExit()
```